# Email threads by subject in Thunderbird (just as in Gmail)

Tags: thunderbird

Is it possible to have threaded email conversations in Thunderbird just like how it is in Gmail? How can I do that?

Comment: check [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/795667/157532)

Answer (score 15):

Use [Thunderbird Conversations](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/gmail-conversation-view/). Never look back :-) Threaded view alone was too little for me.

Comment: Nice find, just installed that & like it.

Comment: Does this extension support the keyboard shortcuts? It doesn't seem to; am I overlooking it?  With Gmail I can really fly using `J`, `K`, `N`, `P`, `O`, `E`, and so on. I would _love_ to have that experience.

Comment: afaik, no. you should file a feature request at https://github.com/protz/GMail-Conversation-View/issues

Comment: I found this plugin very buggy.

Answer (score 11):

Sort of: 
View -> sort by -> threaded.

However, if your answer is not in the folder you're viewing, it is not visible in the thread view.

There's also a plug-in called conversations that usually gives you the gmail look (your mail from 'sent' folder is visible in the conversation view -- most of the times ).

Comment: Is there a Thunderbird equivalent of All Mail folder?

Comment: @Oxwivi: Do you mean the Global Inbox or Unified Folders? http://kb.mozillazine.org/Global_Inbox http://kb.mozillazine.org/Thunderbird_3.1_-_New_Features_and_Changes#Folder_Pane

Comment: @Christoph I mean something that has all sent, received, archived and draft messages in.

Comment: hm, not that I know of. what would be the use-case for that, btw? i don't see it. getting to view mails as conversations, including your sent messages, works with the tb conversations addon (see my other answer), even without having all of them in one folder.

Comment: @Christoph the Gmail model is that there is only _one folder_ called `All Mail`. Everything else is just labels. When a message is "in your inbox", that simply means it has the `Inbox` _label_. When you "archive", it simply removes the `Inbox` label. The message is still sitting in the same folder the whole time.  Ditto for `Sent`. (Of course any message can have multiple labels, which is how you can "file" things in more than one "folder".)

Comment: @Christoph thx! helped me on [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/795667/157532)!

Answer (score 3):

*This answer is a copy of [mine one at SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/795667/157532) following [these rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/24618/222324).*

It "is" built-in on thunderbird now, if you do the right steps:

There is the "Global Inbox" (if there isn't one, you have to activate it at `View >> Folders >> Unified` from [this tip](https://askubuntu.com/a/132858/46437))

Go on its properties at **"Select the folders to search:"**
and click on **"Choose..."**, you will see that your top inbox is checked;
just check the **"sent"** one, click **"ok"**, and **"Update"**.

Now, go to your top "inbox" that is the global one, activate the threaded column and you have a three with all incoming and outgoing messages!